# Is the noun "Nash equilibrium" countable?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I am working in the field of Game theory. I use the word Nash equilibrium intensively, but I always wonder about this word countability.

I think the word Nash equilibrium should be countable. Because for a given game, we can have more than one Nash equilibrium, but I've never seen anyone use words like Nash equilibriums or any other plural form.

So, if this word is countable, what is its plural form. If it is uncountable, how do we express the situation of multiple Nash equilibrium?

Comment: If you want to give people something to think about, go for *multiple Nash **equilibria***. Neither plural form is used very often, but [that version is way more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equilibria%2Cequilibriums&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequilibria%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequilibriums%3B%2Cc0) than the Anglicised "regular" plural ***equilibriums***.

Comment: Have a look at the title of books and papers in your field. Do a search at Google Books. You'll have your answer.